# Serialize LogRecords in Python

Tags: python, logging, serialization

I want to test the logging output of a method.

Everything works good, except I found no easy way to check if the logging which was done is the way I want it to be.

Up to now I get this exception:

```
TypeError: <logging.LogRecord object> is not JSON serializable
```

Here is the code:

```
class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
   def test_foo(self):
        logger=ToListLogger()
        foo=Foo.do_something(logger)
        self.assertEqual('[...]', json.dumps(logger.records))
```

ToListLogger:

```
class ToListLogger(logging.Logger):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ToListLogger, self).__init__('ToListLogger')
        self.records=[]

    def handle(self, record):
        self.records.append(record)
```

I search a way to serialize LogRecord instances to a human readable format. JSON is my favorite, but an other would be acceptable.

My intention: The test should be short, nice and readable.

**Solution**

My Solution, based on the answer of maccinza:

TestCase:

```
class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
   def test_foo(self):
        logger=ToListLogger()
        foo=Foo.do_something(logger)
        self.assertEqual('[...]', logger.to_json())
```

ToListLogger:

```
class ToListLogger(logging.Logger):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ToListLogger, self).__init__('ToListLogger')
        self.records=[]

    def handle(self, record):
        self.records.append(record)

    def to_json(self):
        return LogRecordEncoder().encode(self.records)

class LogRecordEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, logging.LogRecord):
            return dict(msg=obj.msg)
        raise NotImplementedError()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to implement a custom serialization.
It could be as simple as the following:

```
from json import JSONEncoder

class LogEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        try:
            return obj.__dict__ ['records']
        except:
            return obj.__dict__
```

Then, you could serialize your log records:

```
# get your log instance
my_log_instance = ToListLogger()
# populate its records list
# ...
# then serialize it
serialized = LogEncoder().encode(my_log_instance)
```

It will dump you a string representation of your records list.

Comment: Even simpler, your default method could return `obj.records`.

Comment: I added my solution to the answer. It is based on your solution. Thank you!